# Take amazon Alexa number input from users voice and reformat it and make sure it follow validation rules

Tags: json, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am designing an Alexa Skill that takes time entries from a lawyer. For example, Time/description/Date/File. For the File number, I need my JavaScript code on the lambda to take the lawyers input, and return it and save it in the "file" format. Here is an example of a situation to better help you understand:

```
LAWYER: Alexa, File number 664383
```

I would then need Alexa to save that value to my spreadsheet as 664-383. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

**AMAZON.Number**

Use `AMAZON.Number` slot to capture the number input from the user.

Change your interaction model like this.

```
...    
{
  "name": "LawyerIntent",
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "fileNumber",
      "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
    }
  ],
  "samples": [
    "File number {fileNumber}"
  ]
}
...
```

When the lawyer says  (always treat numbers as words, use six instead of 6)

> Alexa, File number six six four three eight three

You will get the number as `fileNumber` slot value in the request generated.

In your Lambda code do the formatting you require.

```
const LawyerIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && request.intent.name === 'LawyerIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log('Inside LawyerIntentHandler');
    const currentIntent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;
    const fileNumber = currentIntent.slots['fileNumber'];

    // Do your  validation 

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak('speech')
        .reprompt('reprompt')
        .getResponse();
    }
};
```